# NiFi Processor Issue

Tags: python, apache-nifi, nifi-processor

In Nifi “ExecuteScript” processor. When the python script (running from “ExecuteScript”  processor) trying to import “unidecode” module throwing error saying “No module found” and the “unidecode” module is installed for Python 2.x on Nifi Server.

Will this work on python 3 or do we require to use different processor.

I tried to resolve a error

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation of the processor [ExecuteScript](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-scripting-nar/1.17.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.script.ExecuteScript/additionalDetails.html)

> The engine listed as "python" in the list of available script engines is actually Jython, not Python. When using Jython, you cannot import pure (CPython) modules such as pandas